# My parents disapprove of my dream of becoming an author but I don’t want to wait till I’m eighteen. What should I do?

Tags: attention

I'm desperate, that all I can say about my situation right now.
My parents planned to make me the next heir of their restaurant yet I want to have a chance in life where I could choose my own career and my own future.
But unfortunately one night, I exploded in tears and demanded to know why they were preventing me from becoming an author.
Like all parents dealing with outbursts and rebellion of their children, they ground them.
It was too much for me when they ground me from going to the public library until next Summer. They took away my Ipad to prevent any typing (I'm using the school laptop to do 'Homework' and writing this explanation.)
I am almost finished with my book but I'm afraid of what will come after next if I brought the subject back up again during dinner.

Comment: What country are you in, and what is your age?

Comment: Seems like an interpersonal skills or parenting SE question, as its not actually about writing.

Comment: It's not like you can't do both.   Writing is a hobby... most of us would love to be paid good money to do nothing but, but the truth is most of us do it for fun and will likely never see good money for it.   There are plenty of ways to do what you want and keep the family business in the family.

Comment: While users here at Writing.SE sympathise with your problem, this question isn't about the craft of writing and is therefore off-topic for our site. You might have better luck at [IPS.SE].

Comment: Truthfully most writers --most artists! --have day jobs. There are famous, well-respected writers who don't make a living at what they do. This does NOT have to be an either/or choice.

Answer (score 4):

Two pieces of advice 'Love what you do' & 'Significant achievement requires hard work and commitment, but you still have to eat.'

Writing a book is not the prerequisite step to be an author.  Selling your book, being paid for your art, is the required step to be an author. Only a tiny minority of authors are able to support themselves with their writing, most have regular jobs: teaching, journalism, computer programming.  And most all writers worked on their first opus while working an unrelated job: bartending, waiting tables, substitute high school teacher, managing a restaurant.

Given the quality of the writing in your question, and ignoring the misspellings and grammatical errors, since you are clearly upset, it's clear you have a lot to learn about being an effective writer and storyteller. And, there is nothing wrong with that.  You are young, it's expected.

If, while you are learning how to be a writer and how to tell engaging stories, you have a way to support yourself, then you are very much advantaged over other aspiring writers, you won't go hungry and you can keep a roof over your head.  This means you can afford to write and learn and submit your work to publishers.  When they start buying your work, and sharing it with the public, and the public, in turn, buys your books, then you'll be in the position to decide what comes next.

If the life of an heir to a restaurant is truly too awful for you, the find something else to do, and love it.  Not do what you love, but love whatever it is you do. Find the joy and satisfaction that comes from doing a job well.  That gives you the mental freedom to pursue the things that you love.  And when Art is the thing you love, it's important to give yourself the proper time and environment to learn the skills and personal insights to express the importance and uniqueness that is you in ways that interest other people.  There is always the chance that you are not very unique and have nothing of value to say, but you will never know unless you give it the best shot you've got.

Comment: @Artemis Silver I guarantee if you publish a book and make money at it, your parents will be impressed, even if they still want you working the restaurant (because they're parents). For legal reasons, you probably won't be able to publish a novel before you're 18 anyway, definitely not without parental support. See if you can get some short stories published in competitions. That builds credentials that will help future publishing. Besides, I've found editing, finding beta readers and rewriting take a lot longer than you might think. You may be 18 before the book gets off the ground anyway.